# 3D georectifying and visualizing wall section of rectangular prism hole dug in ground using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d, 3d-model, orthorectification, archaeology

As part of an archaeological excavation, rectangular holes were dug in the ground at a site and then the sides of the holes were photographed with georeferenced paper target chits. I have created photomosaicked composites of all the pictures taken of the side of a wall using PTGUI, and now I would like to visualize the section in 3D (e.g. ArcGIS Pro or ArcScene). I have tried an old protocol with a hacky workaround that creates an anchor point in ArcScene and then uses the section picture as the symbology for this point at the bottom of the picture after it has been exported from SketchUp. However, the file sizes of the section pictures are too large to load into ArcScene so they only show up as a gray rectangle. I would prefer a simpler and more modern way to this, such as in ArcGIS Pro.

Any ideas?

Below are example pictures of a dirt wall section and how they don't work in ArcScene:

[image]

[image]